# How do I assign a hostname to my ip address when publishing asp.net app to RDP server?

Tags: asp.net, iis, ip, hostname

I managed to publish my web app (just a basic default asp.net MVC project) to a server and I have tried to add a binding in IIS:

[image: IIS Default binding]

The problem I am having is that currently the URL is still shown as the server's IP address (http://79.137.9.186/). I already own a domain name which I could be using for my website (amsterprime.com)

I am using this domain currently for a PHP project.

When I try to change the binding:

[image: IIS Binding changed]

[image: IIS Binding changed overview]

The new url will still lead to my old PHP project:

[image: Default webpage]

What steps do I need to take to assign the domain name to the asp.net web app which is being hosted on given server?

Comment: Giving IP adresses human readable name is the job of a DNS server. There is nothing in the Settings of the ISS or anywhere else. Keep in mind that if you got any relative links on the page, the URL itself is used to build the full request. So you can not exactly fake/lie about this value.

Comment: So I need to look into how DNS servers work then? @Christopher

Comment: Yes. Doing that part is quite literally the DNS servers job. Behind the scenes, it always was and will continue to be IP-adresses being thrown around. But mapping the human readable `amsterprime.com` to the proper IP adress, is a DNS servers job. DynDNS if you do not have a fixed IP adress.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming, but computer networking like the other comments indicated. Should be closed. BTW, setting a host name in IIS Manager might surprise you, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html if later you want to support www.your.site.

Answer (score 1):

When I use **nslookup** command to resolve your dns name, it just resolve the domain to IP 185.xxx.xxx.xxx. Is this the ipaddress of your PHP application server?

So its obviously that your public domain is not pointing to the right IP address. You have to log in the website of your domain provider and map the domain name to your IIS server's address.
Finally, you could run **ipconfig /flushdns** and try to access the website again.

Comment: Where should I run this flush command? On the IIS server or locally or anywhere else?

Comment: @Barrosy On the client that you want to access your IIS site. The command line refresh DNS cache in client side.

Answer (score 0):

This part of the operation of the internet, is a DNS Servers job. Behind the scenes, it has always been IP adresses. But humans can not really use raw IP adresses. So the DNS System was invented.

There is some DNS server resolving `stackoverflow.com` to `151.101.1.69`. Everytime you do a request, the Hostname will be resolved using one of the half dozen layers of DNS resolution and caching.

Without this DNS server, the URL for this post would have to be https://151.101.1.69/questions/57998854/how-do-i-assign-a-hostname-to-my-ip-address-when-publishing-asp-net-app-to-rdp-s

However using the raw IP adress causes some issues with certificate resolution. And of course that the IP adress is far from guaranteed to be static. While not a original goal, being able to change the IP adress a webpage is hosted behind is a use of the DNS system.